# Fitting a very long equation in the page under brackers

Tags: equations, align

I have been trying to fit a very long equation that has curly brackets. So far it is not fitting the page:

[image]

Here is the code below:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        V_{j}\left ( s,q,z \right ) \equiv  \max_{c_{j}^{d}, c_{j}^{m},y_{j}^{d},y_{j}^{m}} \left \{ \omega_{j} u(y_{j}) - v(y_{j}) + \beta \expect*{W\left ( \frac{1}{\psi_{2}(\eta)}\left ( \psi_{2}(\eta)s - c_{j} + y_{j} \right ),\frac{\phi_{1}^{+}}{\phi_{2}(\eta)}\left ( q + \tau_{j}^{c} - c_{j}^{m} + y_{j}^{m} \right ) ,z^{+} \right )|\eta} \right \}.
    \end{aligned} \label{eqn:43}\\
\end{equation}\\
```

Any suggestions on how I am able to fit the equation in the page and in a new nice way?

I am using the expect command:

```
\newcommand{\expect}{\operatorname{E}\expectarg}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\expectarg}[1]{[}{]}{%
    \ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \else\begingroup\fi
    \activatebar#1
    \ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \else\endgroup\fi
}
```

Also using the relevant packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet} % /usepackage{times} is obsolete. These options provide a better implementation of exact same fonts.
\usepackage{mathptmx,courier}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\qunderline[1]{\ThisStyle{%
        \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{-1pt}{\SavedStyle#1}
            {\SavedStyle\underline{\hphantom{#1}}}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}%
}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand\munderbar[1]{%
    \underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}%keeps figures in the text where the page the code is written
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: How or where is `\expect*`defined? Which document class do you employ? Do you require the use of a Times Roman math font? Which font size is in use?

Comment: @Mico I made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, the equation is too long to fit it on a single line. While it's possible (but only just) to fit it on 2 lines, I think it's better to introduce 2 line breaks. I suggest using a single `multline` environment and encase lines 2 and 3 in an `aligned` environment and to align the lines on the fraction terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' environment and '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % mathptmx package is quite old

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}\label{eqn:43}
V_{j} ( s,q,z ) \equiv  
  \smash[b]{\max_{c_{j}^{d}, c_{j}^{m},y_{j}^{d},y_{j}^{m}}} 
  \biggl\{ \, \omega_{j} u(y_{j}) - v(y_{j}) \\
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    {}+ \beta \E \biggl[\, W \biggl( 
    &\frac{1}{\psi_{2}(\eta)}\bigl( \psi_{2}(\eta)s - c_{j} + y_{j} \bigr), \\
    &\frac{\phi_{1}^{+}}{\phi_{2}(\eta)}\bigl( q + \tau_{j}^{c} - c_{j}^{m} + y_{j}^{m} \bigr) , z^{+} \biggr) 
\biggm|\eta\,\biggr] \biggr\}\,.
  \end{aligned}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: After I posted the answer shown above, the OP provided further information about the document setup, including the fact that the margins are narrower (and hence the textblock is quite a bit wider) than the default employed in the initial answer. Taking this additional piece of information into account, I would no longer recommend using a 3-line `multline`-based setup, as lines 2 and 3 would get shifted rather far to the right and make them look barely connected to line 1.

Instead, I would employ either a 2-line `multline` setup or a solution that employs nested `aligned` environments inside an `equation` environment. The first `aligned` environment serves to align rows 1 and 2, while the second, nested, `aligned` environment serves to position row 3 relative to row 2. Both solutions are illustrated below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' environment and '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % mathptmx package is quite old

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{42} % just for this example
\begin{multline}\label{eqn:43}
V_{j} ( s,q,z ) \equiv  
  \max_{c_{j}^{d}, c_{j}^{m},y_{j}^{d},y_{j}^{m}} \biggl\{
   \, \omega_{j} u(y_{j}) - v(y_{j}) \\
  %\begin{aligned}[b]
    + \beta \E \biggl[\, W \biggl( 
    \frac{1}{\psi_{2}(\eta)}\bigl( \psi_{2}(\eta)s - c_{j} + y_{j} \bigr), %\\
    \frac{\phi_{1}^{+}}{\phi_{2}(\eta)}\bigl( q + \tau_{j}^{c} - c_{j}^{m} + y_{j}^{m} \bigr) , z^{+} \biggr) 
\biggm|\eta\,\biggr] \biggr\}\,.
  %\end{aligned}
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:44}
\begin{aligned}[b]
V_{j} ( s,q,z ) \equiv  
  \smash[b]{\max_{c_{j}^{d}, c_{j}^{m},y_{j}^{d},y_{j}^{m}}} 
  \biggl\{ &\, \omega_{j} u(y_{j}) - v(y_{j}) \\
  &\begin{aligned}[b]
    {}+ \beta \E \biggl[\, W \biggl( 
    &\frac{1}{\psi_{2}(\eta)}\bigl( \psi_{2}(\eta)s - c_{j} + y_{j} \bigr), \\
    &\frac{\phi_{1}^{+}}{\phi_{2}(\eta)}\bigl( q + \tau_{j}^{c} - c_{j}^{m} + y_{j}^{m} \bigr) , z^{+} \biggr) 
\biggm|\eta\,\biggr] \biggr\}\,.
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```